# Install google oauth2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to install google oauth2 in django.

I have tried installing `sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

But still gets error at importing.
Imports are:

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests
```

I still get red marks at import.

Is it correctly installed or anything else to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The package you've installed doesn't have the modules you're trying to import, hence the error. You might be looking for [`google-auth`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-auth) instead of `google-api-python-client`.

Comment: you can always check the modules that are installed with `pip freeze`

Comment: I have also installed **google-auth** but no change.

Comment: Can you show us the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues but finally found the required packages.
Here are my `requirements`

```
google==2.0.2
google-api-python-client==1.7.8
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.3.0
```

Hope this will help.